# How to get selected item in grouped list View

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Grouped ListView,now i need to access the items in that group,when I click on the item present in the grouplist,I need to get particular details of that item,

```
 <ListView x:Name="DishesList" ItemsSource ="{Binding Details}" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemTapped = "OnItemSelected" IsGroupingEnabled="True" >
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding ="10" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout Grid.Column= "1">
                                <Label Text ="{Binding Name}" TextColor ="#007aff" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding = "1" Spacing = "0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <Image x:Name="DishImage" Source = "{Binding DishImage}" HeightRequest="60" />
                            <Label x:Name="DishName" Text ="{Binding DishName}" TextColor ="#007aff" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">

                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
 var selectedItem = (DishesModel)eventArgs.SelectedItem;
                 //How can I access the data of the Particular item?,Iam getting all the items which are present in that group but i need to get one among them on which  clicked.
            }
```

Comment: Is `DishesModel` the name of the class for the particular item you're looking for? Or are you trying to get a `Dish` item or something with another class name?  What is the data type of `Details` that you're binding the `ItemSource` to?

Answer (score 0):

if you need item selection then use **ItemSelected** instead of **ItemTapped** in XAML.

and u need tapped item then change **SelectedItemChangedEventArgs** to **ItemTappedEventArgs** and **eventArgs.SelectedItem** to **eventArgs.Item** in XAML.CS

Answer (score 0):

Within the `ListView.ItemTemplate`'s `DataTemplate` add a `TapGestureRecognizer` that is using its containing page as the binding source and supply a binding path to the `ICommand` that implements the `Command` that you what to call when the item in a group is tapped, and finally set the `CommandParameter` to be bound to itself (i.e. the item within the group).

Something like:

```
<ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference theContainingPage}, Path=BindingContext.TapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
</ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
```

### Example:

#### XAML:

```
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="Forms_App_Project.Views.GroupListTapExample"
    x:Name="theContainingPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>        
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}" IsGroupingEnabled="true">
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Heading}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ContentView>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference theContainingPage}, Path=BindingContext.TapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                        </ContentView>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>        
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

#### Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GroupedItems : List<Item>
{
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items => this;
}
```

#### `Code-behind` on that page:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class GroupListTapExample : ContentPage
{
    readonly ICommand tapCommand;
    List<GroupedItems> _listOfPeople;
    public List<GroupedItems> ListOfItems { get { return _listOfPeople; } set { _listOfPeople = value; base.OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public GroupListTapExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tapCommand = new Command(OnTapped);

        var aList = new GroupedItems()
        {
            new Item() { Name = "Aa" },
            new Item() { Name = "Ab" }
        };
        aList.Heading = "A";

        var bList = new GroupedItems()
        {
            new Item() { Name = "Ba" },
            new Item() { Name = "Bb" }
        };
        bList.Heading = "B";

        var list = new List<GroupedItems>()
        {
            aList,
            bList
        };
        ListOfItems = list;

        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public ICommand TapCommand
    {
        get { return tapCommand; }
    }

    void OnTapped(object parameter)
    {
        var item = parameter as Item;
        DisplayAlert("Tapped", $"{item.Name}", "Cool");
    }
}
```